# Values are not showing in SQL table

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Values are inserted into the table but values are not showing in the output table. Anyone have the solution please explain[[Here is the SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohUq9.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQexh.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flzOF.jpg)

The SQL query and the output table is here

Comment: Please post your code as test instead of an image.

Comment: Hi. - please don’t link to images. Add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you were deceived by the result grid; it is showing the columns from Teacher, not from Dept.